# Improving performance on a tkinter scrollable canvas with many widgets inside

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollable canvas in tkinter, filled with a grid of smaller square canvases. I have no problem setting this up, but the result is very slow when scrolling. Any advice on how to speed things up? I have considered, but have yet to try to implement:

- Using pages of many widgets rather than one scrollable canvas. This would solve the problem, but I'd like to use a scrolling solution if possible.
- When scrolling, have the canvas "snap" to the nearest row of squares. The scrolling does not need to be continuous, e.g. we don't need to see half a square at a time.
- Change the canvas to only contain the squares that are currently being viewed. All windows that aren't being viewed can be destroyed and created again later. I am unclear if this approach will even help, but a similar approach worked well for a large image on a different project I've worked on.
- It could be possible that this lag is just a hardware issue on my end. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to test this.

Here is the reprex, any help is appreciated! Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
outside = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
outside.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

def get_box():  # box is 16x16 pixels
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
    color = np.random.choice(colors, 1)[0]
    ret = tk.Canvas(canvas, bg=color, width=16, height=16, highlightthickness=0)
    return ret

canvas = tk.Canvas(outside, width=16*30, bg='gray20', highlightthickness=0). # 30 columns
canvas.pack(fill='y', expand=True, side='left')
scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(outside,  orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)  # Create scrollbar
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right', expand=True)

for i in range(600):  # create many boxes. ideally, ~4000 once things are running smoothly
    box = get_box()
    canvas.create_window(16 * (i % 30), 16 * (i //30), anchor='nw', window=box)

canvas.update_idletasks()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
root.mainloop()
```